# JavaFX 2.2 using a second window with FXML

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2

I read a lot of posts with the same problem, but I can't fix it and find a usefull answer.

I want to create an application with the option to open a new window to enter, edit, delete some data.

I have a `Main.java` shown like this:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception{

        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("MainWindow.fxml"));
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 1000, 700);

        stage.setTitle("FXML Welcome");
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}​
```

And for this I have a `MainWindowController.java`

```
import java.net.URL;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;

public class MainWindowController implements Initializable {

    String ComboCompany = null;
    String ComboModellName = null;
    String ComboTyp = null;

    @FXML
    protected void handelAddButtonAction(ActionEvent event) {
        System.out.println("Add");
    }

    @FXML
    protected void handelEditButtonAction(ActionEvent event) {
        System.out.println("edit");
    }

    @FXML
    protected void handelUpdateButtonAction(ActionEvent event) {
        System.out.println("update");
    }

    @FXML
    protected void handelDelButtonAction(ActionEvent event) {
        System.out.println("del");
    }

    @FXML
    protected void handelCloseButtonAction(ActionEvent event) {
        Platform.exit();
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {

    }
}
```

A new `AddWindow.fxml` is creates and ready to use. Shall I have to create a new `AddWindowController.java` or can I write some code in a new class?

The biggest question is, how can I solve that I click on the button "Add" that a new window pops up to enter data and close it?

Exception:

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1762)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1645)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
at javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8216)
at javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Button.java:185)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(ButtonBehavior.java:182)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:96)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:89)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3724)
at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Scene.java:3452)
at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1728)
at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2461)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:348)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:273)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:382)
at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:553)
at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:925)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$141(WinApplication.java:102)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication$$Lambda$37/1147985808.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:71)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:275)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1757)
... 47 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Location is not set.
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2428)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2403)
at multiscreeninput.MainWindowController.openInputWindow(MainWindowController.java:26)
... 57 more
```

Answer (score 4):

I have created a small example based on your question, in which we can **edit** the `text of a Label` present on the `MainWindow`, using a child window.

It takes input from a `TextField` preset in the `child window` and updates the `Label` on the `MainWindow`.

You can use the same to add the other requirement as well.

*All files are inside a package `multiscreeninput`*

**Main.java**

```
package multiscreeninput;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception{

        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/multiscreeninput/MainWindow.fxml"));
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 200, 200);
        stage.setTitle("FXML Welcome");
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

**MainWindow.fxml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<VBox maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" fx:controller="multiscreeninput.MainWindowController" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
   <children>
      <HBox alignment="CENTER" prefHeight="100.0" prefWidth="200.0">
         <children>
            <Label fx:id="label" text="Use to button to edit data" wrapText="true" />
         </children>
      </HBox>
      <HBox alignment="CENTER" prefHeight="100.0" prefWidth="200.0">
         <children>
            <Button fx:id="button" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#openInputWindow" text="Change Text" />
         </children>
      </HBox>
   </children>
</VBox>
```

**MainWindowController.java**

```
package multiscreeninput;

import java.io.IOException;

import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Modality;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class MainWindowController {

    @FXML
    Button button;

    @FXML
    Label label;

    public void openInputWindow(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("Child.fxml"));
        VBox newWindow = (VBox)loader.load();
        ChildController controller = loader.getController();
        controller.setMainWindow(this);
        Stage stage = new Stage();
        stage.initModality(Modality.WINDOW_MODAL);
        stage.initOwner(button.getScene().getWindow());
        Scene scene = new Scene(newWindow);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();   
    }

    public StringProperty getLabelTextProperty() {
        return label.textProperty();
    }
}
```

**Child.fxml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.geometry.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<VBox alignment="CENTER" fillWidth="false" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" spacing="20.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="multiscreeninput.ChildController">
   <children>
      <TextField fx:id="text">
         <VBox.margin>
            <Insets />
         </VBox.margin></TextField>
      <Button fx:id="button" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#saveAndClose" text="Save and Close" />
   </children>
   <padding>
      <Insets top="10.0" />
   </padding>
</VBox>
```

**ChildController.java**

```
package multiscreeninput;

import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;

public class ChildController {

    @FXML
    TextField text;

    @FXML
    Button button;

    private MainWindowController mainWindow;


    public void setMainWindow(MainWindowController mainWindow){
        this.mainWindow = mainWindow;
    }

    public void saveAndClose(ActionEvent event){
        mainWindow.getLabelTextProperty().bind(text.textProperty());
        ((Button)event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow().hide();
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, but it dosent work, only Errors by pushing the button

Comment: Can you paste a link to the error? Did you place the files inside a package `multiscreeninput`

Comment: It works fine. The question is if it's a proper way to handle it and if it's ok to hide the window after using it..

Comment: Please add screenshot

Answer (score 1):

I have a sample code which opens ROOT -> FATHER -> SON -> GRANDSON windows in that order. There is no other processing involved, just click on NEXT button and it will open it's child. This was developed in Netbeans IDE version 8.02 and JavaFX version 8x.

### This is the Main Program - TESTMULTILEVEL.JAVA which opens the ROOTWindow.FXML

```
package testmultilevel;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

/**
 *
 * @author Hornigold Arthur
 */
public class TestMultiLevel extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("RootWindow.fxml"));

        Scene scene = new Scene(root,300,300);
        stage.setTitle("This is the ROOT WINDOW");

        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

### This is the ROOT FXML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.text.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import java.util.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" prefHeight="200" prefWidth="320" style="-fx-background-color: cornsilk; -fx-border-color: red; -fx-border-style: solid; -fx-border-width: 3;" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.40" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="testmultilevel.RootWindowController">
    <children>
        <Button fx:id="btnNext" layoutX="126.0" layoutY="161.0" onAction="#handleBtnNext" text="Next">
         <font>
            <Font name="Bookman Old Style Bold" size="14.0" />
         </font></Button>
        <Label fx:id="label" layoutX="84.0" layoutY="32.0" minHeight="16" minWidth="69" text="This is the ROOT" textAlignment="CENTER">
         <font>
            <Font name="Bookman Old Style Bold" size="14.0" />
         </font></Label>
    </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

### This is the ROOT Program

```
package testmultilevel;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Modality;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;

public class RootWindowController {

    @FXML
    private ResourceBundle resources;

    @FXML
    private URL location;

    @FXML
    private Button btnNext;

    @FXML
    private Label label;

    @FXML
    void handleBtnNext(ActionEvent event) {

        System.out.println("Opening the FATHER Window");
        try {
            openInputWindow(event);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(RootWindowController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

    @FXML
    void initialize() {
        assert btnNext != null : "fx:id=\"btnNext\" was not injected: check your FXML file 'RootWindow.fxml'.";
        assert label != null : "fx:id=\"label\" was not injected: check your FXML file 'RootWindow.fxml'.";

    }

    public void openInputWindow(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("Father.fxml"));
        AnchorPane newWindow = (AnchorPane) loader.load();
        FatherController controller = loader.getController();
        controller.setMainWindow(this);
        Stage stage = new Stage();
        stage.setTitle("Father Window");
        stage.initModality(Modality.WINDOW_MODAL);
        stage.initOwner(btnNext.getScene().getWindow());
        Scene scene = new Scene(newWindow);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

}
```

### This is the FATHER FXML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.text.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import java.util.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" prefHeight="200" prefWidth="320" style="-fx-background-color: cornsilk; -fx-border-color: red; -fx-border-style: solid; -fx-border-width: 3;" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.40" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="testmultilevel.FatherController">
    <children>
        <Button fx:id="btnNext" layoutX="126.0" layoutY="161.0" onAction="#handleBtnNext" text="Next">
         <font>
            <Font name="Bookman Old Style Bold" size="14.0" />
         </font></Button>
        <Label fx:id="label" layoutX="84.0" layoutY="32.0" minHeight="16" minWidth="69" text="This is the FATHER" textAlignment="CENTER">
         <font>
            <Font name="Bookman Old Style Bold" size="14.0" />
         </font></Label>
    </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

### This is the FATHER Controller

```
package testmultilevel;

import static java.awt.SystemColor.text;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.stage.Modality;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class FatherController {

    @FXML
    private ResourceBundle resources;

    @FXML
    private URL location;

    @FXML
    private Button btnNext;

    @FXML
    private Label label;

    private RootWindowController rootWindow;

    public void setMainWindow(RootWindowController rootWindow){
        this.rootWindow = rootWindow;
    }

    @FXML
    void handleBtnNext(ActionEvent event) {

        System.out.println("Opening the Son Window");
        try {
            openInputWindow(event);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(RootWindowController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

    @FXML
    void initialize() {
        assert btnNext != null : "fx:id=\"btnNext\" was not injected: check your FXML file 'RootWindow.fxml'.";
        assert label != null : "fx:id=\"label\" was not injected: check your FXML file 'RootWindow.fxml'.";

    }

    public void openInputWindow(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("Son.fxml"));
        AnchorPane newWindow = (AnchorPane) loader.load();
        SonController controller = loader.getController();
        controller.setMainWindow(this);
        Stage stage = new Stage();
        stage.setTitle("Son Window");
        stage.initModality(Modality.WINDOW_MODAL);
        stage.initOwner(btnNext.getScene().getWindow());
        Scene scene = new Scene(newWindow);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }
}
```

### This is the SON FXML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.text.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import java.util.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" prefHeight="200" prefWidth="320" style="-fx-background-color: cornsilk; -fx-border-color: red; -fx-border-style: solid; -fx-border-width: 3;" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.40" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="testmultilevel.SonController">
    <children>
        <Button fx:id="btnNext" layoutX="126.0" layoutY="161.0" onAction="#handleBtnNext" text="Next">
         <font>
            <Font name="Bookman Old Style Bold" size="14.0" />
         </font></Button>
        <Label fx:id="label" layoutX="84.0" layoutY="32.0" minHeight="16" minWidth="69" text="This is the SON" textAlignment="CENTER">
         <font>
            <Font name="Bookman Old Style Bold" size="14.0" />
         </font></Label>
    </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

### This is the SON Controller

```
package testmultilevel;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.stage.Modality;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class SonController {

    @FXML
    private ResourceBundle resources;

    @FXML
    private URL location;

    @FXML
    private Button btnNext;

    @FXML
    private Label label;

    private FatherController FatherWindow;

    public void setMainWindow(FatherController FatherWindow){
        this.FatherWindow = FatherWindow;
    }

    @FXML
    void handleBtnNext(ActionEvent event) {

        System.out.println("Opening the Grand Son Window");
        try {
            openInputWindow(event);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(RootWindowController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

    @FXML
    void initialize() {
        assert btnNext != null : "fx:id=\"btnNext\" was not injected: check your FXML file 'RootWindow.fxml'.";
        assert label != null : "fx:id=\"label\" was not injected: check your FXML file 'RootWindow.fxml'.";

    }

    public void openInputWindow(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("GrandSon.fxml"));
        AnchorPane newWindow = (AnchorPane) loader.load();
        GrandSonController controller = loader.getController();
        controller.setMainWindow(this);
        Stage stage = new Stage();
        stage.setTitle("Grand Son Window");
        stage.initModality(Modality.WINDOW_MODAL);
        stage.initOwner(btnNext.getScene().getWindow());
        Scene scene = new Scene(newWindow);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }
}
```

### This is the GRAND SON FXML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.text.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import java.util.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" prefHeight="200" prefWidth="320" style="-fx-background-color: cornsilk; -fx-border-color: red; -fx-border-style: solid; -fx-border-width: 3;" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.40" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="testmultilevel.GrandSonController">
    <children>
        <Button fx:id="btnNext" layoutX="126.0" layoutY="161.0" onAction="#handleBtnNext" text="Next">
         <font>
            <Font name="Bookman Old Style Bold" size="14.0" />
         </font></Button>
        <Label fx:id="label" layoutX="84.0" layoutY="32.0" minHeight="16" minWidth="69" text="This is the GRANDSON" textAlignment="CENTER">
         <font>
            <Font name="Bookman Old Style Bold" size="14.0" />
         </font></Label>
    </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

### This is the GRAND SON Controller.

```
package testmultilevel;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;

public class GrandSonController {

    @FXML
    private ResourceBundle resources;

    @FXML
    private URL location;

    @FXML
    private Button btnNext;

    @FXML
    private Label label;

    private SonController SonWindow;

    public void setMainWindow(SonController SonWindow){
        this.SonWindow = SonWindow;
    }

   @FXML
    void handleBtnNext(ActionEvent event) {

    }

    @FXML
    void initialize() {
        assert btnNext != null : "fx:id=\"btnNext\" was not injected: check your FXML file 'RootWindow.fxml'.";
        assert label != null : "fx:id=\"label\" was not injected: check your FXML file 'RootWindow.fxml'.";

    }
}
```

I did not try to Generalize the creating the Child window as a separate function and call it with appropriate parameters, so that I don't have to repeat the following piece of code in each CONTROLLER.

```
    public void openInputWindow(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("GrandSon.fxml"));
    AnchorPane newWindow = (AnchorPane) loader.load();
    GrandSonController controller = loader.getController();
    controller.setMainWindow(this);
    Stage stage = new Stage();
    stage.setTitle("Grand Son Window");
    stage.initModality(Modality.WINDOW_MODAL);
    stage.initOwner(btnNext.getScene().getWindow());
    Scene scene = new Scene(newWindow);
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
}
```